# How do I break the if statement, and return to the beggining of my loop?

Tags: python, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I want to make a lcd screen going to the same colour, like the colour of the button you push. My problem now is, if I push the button, it infinitely prints 'rbutton ok' (or 'ybutton ok'). How do I get python to just print it once and to go back to the beginning of the loop again?

```
from machine import Pin
import time


ybutton = Pin(14, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_DOWN)
rbutton = Pin(15, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_DOWN)
gbutton = Pin(13, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_DOWN)

while True:
    if ybutton.value():

        print("ybutton ok")
    elif rbutton.value():
        print("rbutton ok")
```

I tried to use `continue` at the end of the `if` statements, but that didn't work, cause the program got stuck on the print command...

Comment: The code *does* go back to the beginning of the loop; that's why you get an infinite stream of message.

Comment: Presumably, `value()` returns the current state of the button, regardless of how long the button as been *in* that state.

Comment: Starting from @chepner last comment, you could print the message only when the value you read in the current iteration is different from the value in the previous iteration. To do this, you have to assign the value of each button to a variable at the end of each iteration.

Comment: Alternatively, you can read the [documentation](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/machine.Pin.html) to understand how to set the `Pin` value to 0 after printing the message.

Comment: Here is link: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-exit-if-statement

Answer (score 0):

That should do what you want:

```
from machine import Pin 
import time


ybutton = Pin(14, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_DOWN) 
rbutton = Pin(15, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_DOWN) 
gbutton = Pin(13, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_DOWN)

setButtonText = False 
while True:
    if setButtonText == False:
        setButtonText = True
        if ybutton.value():
            print("ybutton ok")
        elif rbutton.value():
            print("rbutton ok")
```

Alternatively:

```
from machine import Pin 
import time


ybutton = Pin(14, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_DOWN) 
rbutton = Pin(15, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_DOWN) 
gbutton = Pin(13, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_DOWN)

lastButtonPressed
while True:
    if ybutton.value() and lastButtonPressed != ybutton:
        lastButtonIdPressed = ybutton
        print("ybutton ok")
    elif rbutton.value() and lastButtonPressed != rbutton:
        lastButtonPressed= rbutton
        print("rbutton ok")
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be possible to reset `setButtonText` to `False` at some point in the loop?

Comment: Yes, that could be implemented, but that was not in the question, or did I misunderstood?

Comment: Based on the original code, I assume OP wants *one*  message each time a (different) button is pushed, indicating when the color changed. (Otherwise, you could use `break` as soon as any button press is detected to leave the loop.)

Comment: I added a second solution that should solve that issue

Comment: Hmm... now it is not doing anything...

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to do another while loop, maybe include a counter to keep track of how many times you want it to run (presumably once). Something like this:

```py
val = 0
    while True:
        while val < 1:
            print("ybutton ok")
            val += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use break to exit an if statement in a for or a while loop.

Does this help?

Snippet:

```
while True:
    if ybutton.value():

        print("ybutton ok")
        break
    if rbutton.value():
        print("rbutton ok")
        break
```